# javascript the OO way - permission denied error on IE

Tags: javascript

I am trying some javascript like below:

```
var obj = {
    resetCss: function(){
        $("#canvas > div").click{function(){
             val = $(this).attr("id"); //I get the expected value
             obj.setCss(val);
         });
    },
    setCss: function(inp){
       alert (inp);
    },
    getCss: function(){

    }
};
```

Mark up:

```
    <div id="canvas">
    <div id="can1">Canvas 1</div>
    <div id="can2">Canvas 2</div>
    <div id="can3">Canvas 3</div>
    <div id="can4">Canvas 4</div>
    <div id="can5">Canvas 5</div>
    </div>
```

This one works well on FF, Chrome, Safari etc. Only on IE browsers when the script hits "obj.setCss(val);" I get an error "permission denied" and the script execution terminates. Can someone help me with this please?

Thanks,
L

Comment: We need more context. In which context are you calling the methods? Your are missing commatas btw. And what exactly "works" in the other browsers?

Comment: Those `// some code here` is probably where the error is :)

Comment: Can you include usage examples? And you appear to have removed a bunch of code assuming that it's not relevant, despite the fact that you don't know where the issue is. Seems odd. And not very helpful!

Comment: Not sure, but your example is missing commas after each function...

Comment: What works is I get the alert and I get that error in IE instead. I have added my code to make it clear. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I had found another way of doing what I wanted to. Thanks everyone for your time and response.

Answer (score 0):

You have a { rather than ( in the resetCss function. See below. This is probably being ignored in the other browsers but not IE

```
var obj = {
    resetCss: function(){
        $("#id").click(function(){ // <---- Note the ( rather than {
           val = $(this).val(); //I get the expected value
           obj.setCss(val);
         });
    },
    setCss: function(inp){
        //some code here
       alert (inp);
    },
    getCss: function(){

    }
};
```

Comment: That was my typo in here and not present in the code. Thanks for your resposne though.

Comment: In that case, the error must be in the // some code here bit as it works fine in IE. Here's an example - http://jsfiddle.net/VZpHP/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
    resetCss: function(){
        $("#canvas > div").click{function(){ //I think your code wrong here
             val = $(this).attr("id"); //I get the expected value
             obj.setCss(val);
         });
    },
    setCss: function(inp){
       alert (inp);
    },
    getCss: function(){

    }
};
```

It should change to

```
var obj = {
    resetCss: function(){
        $("#canvas > div").click(function(){ //Change { to (
             val = $(this).attr("id"); //I get the expected value
             obj.setCss(val);
         });
    },
    setCss: function(inp){
       alert (inp);
    },
    getCss: function(){

    }
};
```